# ES6 How to get _this inside class, inside another context

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I was searching and can't find a proper way to figure out this in ES6 way.

```
class MyClass {
  // i can't event decalre _this/_self here
  constructor() {
     setTimeout(function(){
        // other work..
        hiUser(); // this.hiUser() or //_this.hiUser() not working
     },1000);
   }
   hiUser(){
     alert('Hi');
   }
}
```

Comment: If you were going to set `self` you'd do it inside the constructor, not inside the class. But just use an arrow function like @Buzinas said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [fat arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.hiUser();
    }, 1000);
  }

  hiUser(){
    alert('Hi');
  }
}
```

Or you can use the simple [ES5's `Function.prototype.bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.hiUser();
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  hiUser(){
    alert('Hi');
  }
}
```

---

There is an [ES7 proposal to shorthand the `Function.prototype.bind`](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind) method, so, depending on the transpiler (e.g Babel or Typescript) you're (possibly) using, you can set the ES7 flags and use it today:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(::function() {
      this.hiUser();
    }, 1000);
  }

  hiUser(){
    alert('Hi');
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't just want to call hiUser i also need a function where i can do other things as well.

Comment: @dev.mraj You can just use curly brackets and put whatever you want. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for fat arrow functions.... great.

Comment: @X.L.Ant because if you bind the method inside of the timeout, "this" is already something else

Comment: @X.L.Ant according to the OP, he wants to put more code inside the function, not only calling `this.hiUser`.

Comment: @Buzinas you should add an example using ES7's "::" bind syntax (`this::setTimeout( ... );`)

Comment: Also, I would remove that last example, because now, in the hiUser method, 'this' no longer refers to the class (which is generally a bad idea). I would stick with the lambda.

Comment: @Nick Alright, done! :)

Comment: @dev.mraj if my answer was useful to you, please mark it as the accepted! :)

Comment: Please stop calling them "fat arrow" functions. This is a leftover from coffeescript. They're just [arrow functions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions).

Comment: For people coming to this via the route I did, which was figuring out why "this" wasn't behaving properly, I found this section specifically helpful from the first link in this answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this "An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this from its enclosing scope."

Answer (score 10):

The previous answers only gave you code samples on how to fix it; Let me explain your issue and why it's happening

In your code example, the function inside of your setTimeout is being bound to the `this` value of the setTimeout (which is generally `window` or `undefined` in strict mode).

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // this === window
}, 1000);
```

---

In ES6, they introduced lambda expressions (**arrow functions**) which are "*lexically bound*" -- meaning that they borrow the `this` value from their outside scope. In your case, that's the class/object.

In order to leverage the **lambda expression**s, it would look like:

```
class Foo {

    constructor () {
        setTimeout(() => this.myMethod(), 1000);
    }

    myMethod () {
        console.log('foo');
    }
}
```

---

If you're using Babel to transpile your code, and are using experimental features, you can use ES7's **binding** syntax to solve your problem as well.

If you bind a function/method, it creates a copy of that function, and binds the `this` value to whatever you choose. This will allow you to use the `function` statement that will be bound to your class/object.

`<context to be bound> :: <function to receive context>`

```
class Foo {

    constructor () {
        setTimeout(this::function() {
            this.myMethod();
        }, 1000);
    }

    myMethod () {
        console.log('foo');
    }
}
```

An even shorter version would look something like the following

```
constructor () {
    setTimeout(this::this.myMethod, 1000);
}
```

If you're still having issues understanding this, I suggest you read more about ES6 classes and javascript binding.

Comment: Please stop calling them "fat arrow" functions. This is a leftover from coffeescript. They're just [arrow functions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions).

Comment: @naomik I prefer to call them lambdas; I just use arrow functions to make sure that people know what I'm referring to.

Comment: Sure, "lambda", "anonymous function", "closure", whatever. If you read the spec I linked, ECMAScript calls them "arrow functions". My point is you didn't call them "arrow functions", you called them "**fat** arrow functions", which is coffeescript lingo.

Comment: Yeah, I usually don't -- it was in my head after reading the other answer here.

Answer (score -1):

`setTimeout` might have its own `this` context. You could set `_self` in the constructor though, or use arrow functions:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor () {
        var self = this;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: its not es6 way. i can do this before.

Comment: @dev.mraj `// i can't event decalre _this/_self here` This doesn't make clear that you didn't want this solution.

Comment: i mean to say that i can't declare out of class

Comment: What @X.L.Ant said...